Constraints on pod_sandbox_id or container_id
I'm designing a custom container runtime and was wondering if there are any constraints on the values supplied for pod_sandbox_id or container_id. Nothing appears to be documented, but surely there must be something? At least a length constraint?
This matters because I must decide pretty early on if it's OK to encode some useful information into those IDs, or if I must keep track of that information separately and use simpler IDs. If both types of ID can definitely handle, say, 256 arbitrary ASCII characters, then it would probably make sense to go ahead and encode that information directly in the ID's so I didn't have to look it up separately. But would longer ID's also have performance implications? Looking for any tips.

Part of the philosophy of using a string for everything is constraints aren't real. Where most organizations fail is in naming, and proper naming could include some of these id's. And some environments have id fields that are hashed values of multiple other fields and the actual "id" is mostly useless/misleading by itself.
